# Run https to localhost XAMPP

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp, localhost

I'm currently working on a QR scanner website (HTML5, PHP & MySQL), but I'm not going to host it on a domain; instead, I'll use it with the localhost over the network. However, because I will be needing  the use of the camera to scan, I think I  must change the http to https since according to my research, cameras can't run with http because it requires a permission. Is it possible for me to change the localhost to https or do you have any suggestion on how can I make it work? I'm new with this area so please help me. Thank you!

Comment: use this tutorial https://www.ssldragon.com/blog/install-an-ssl-certificate-on-xampp/ it explains in detail how to configure xampp

Comment: You can use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) to get a free SSL certificate. It is easily maintained by [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions).

Comment: I'm going to try it! Thank you so much for the reference!

Comment: @nbk hello! I'm currently in the step for the CSR generator; there is a form that I need to fill out to get a 'CSR,' but there is a field that requires the 'Common Name,' what will I put there if I'm going to use the localhost?

Comment: Try just making your 'Common Name' `localhost`. Alternatively host the website at `scanner.localhost` or something.

Comment: @cam noted with this. I can also view the site to my mobile after doing all the steps, right? I just need to enter the `scanner.localhost` to the URL to access it?

Comment: To access `scanner.localhost` on your mobile after doing these steps you'll need to run a proxy server on the dev machine and then configure your mobile network settings to use the IP of your dev machine as the proxy server. You can follow a guide on how to do this, which proxy you use will depend on the OS of your dev machine hosting the website.

Comment: @cam I already make it https and it is now working on mobile. Thank you so much!